# installing python package - no logging configuration

Tags: python

I have just installed a python package called "Bacon", but whenever I import it, it comes up with a few errors.

Error:

```
WARNING: No logging configuration for "bacon" set; using default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import bacon
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bacon.all import *
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\all.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bacon.core import *
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\core.py", line 152, in <module>
    lib = native.load(function_wrapper = _error_wrapper)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\native.py", line 493, in load
    _lib = _dll_path.get_lib()
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\native.py", line 428, in get_lib
    dll_dir = self.get_dir()
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\native.py", line 396, in get_dir
    _pkg_resources = __import__('pkg_resources', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ValueError: level must be >= 0
```

**How can this be fixed? And why is it doing it?**

Thanks

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, even though the title says "no logging configuration", that's just a warning and the real problem is on the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

in your main module do at the beginning something like

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(logging.INFO)
```

It inits the default logging config and sets the level..

Comment: In Python 3.3 this did not work, but `logging.basicConfig(filename='temp.log',level=logging.INFO)` silences the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permissions, change this line (File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\bacon\native.py", line 396):

```
_pkg_resources = __import__('pkg_resources', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

to

```
_pkg_resources = __import__('pkg_resources', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

`level` refers to the last argument.

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#__import__):

> Changed in version 3.3: Negative values for level are no longer supported (which also changes the default value to 0).

Comment: Or just use Python 2.7 :)

Comment: This didn't work, should I just download 2.7? Is it basically the same as 3.3?

Comment: Downloading and installing 2.7 is not worth the trouble. After editing that line, do you get the same message? Please update the question if you get a different error.

Comment: This: `ValueError: level must be >= 0`?

Comment: I installed Python 3.3 and bacon 0.2.7, and the change from `-1` to `0` was enough to make `import bacon` work, except for the warning. I can also run the examples that come with the package.